# Matrix Diagonalization programming

Tags: functions, matrix, programming, linear-algebra

I have a very simple problem, with me misunderstanding the use of `Module`s and `Function`s in general, in *Mathematica*.

I have a function of which I want to input a matrix, and in the function I have a need of knowing the number of columns to make operations upon these. To this I use `Dimensions[]`, which works fine while using a matrix directly, but seems to fail whenever I try to input the formula to a function and/or `Module`.

The following lines works when using a matrix directly, yet if I want to save the output directly, I can't seem to make it work:

```
OrtMat[X_] = Module[{m = Dimensions[X][[2]]},
  For[i = 1, i < m + 1, i++,
   If[i > 1,
     For[j = 1, j < i, j++,
      X[[All, i]] = 
       X[[All, i]] - 
        X[[All, i]].X[[All, j]]/Norm[X[[All, j]]]*X[[All, j]];
      X[[All, i]] = X[[All, i]]/Norm[X[[All, i]]];
      ],
     X[[All, i]] = X[[All, i]]/Norm[X[[All, i]]]
    ];
   ]
  ]
```

which very simply orthogonalizes the matrix. As said the only error popping up is with dimensions, it comes with the output:

> ```
> Part::partw: Part 2 of {} does not exist. >>
> ```

Comment: Have you seen `Orthogonalize[]` and `Eigensystem[]`?

Answer (score 3):

This makes your code work with some "style" modifications. The main problem was that you were assigning a value to the (immutable) parameter in the function. Use a scoped symbol instead.

Anyway, all those linear algebra functions are part of the Mathematica standard repertoire

```
OrtMat[y_] := Module[{m = Last@Dimensions[y], x = y},
  x[[1]] = Normalize@x[[1]];
  For[i = 2, i <= m, i++,
   For[j = 1, j < i, j++,
    x[[i]] = x[[i]] - (x[[i]].x[[j]]) Normalize@x[[j]];
    x[[i]] = Normalize@x[[i]];
    ]
   ];
  x]

OrtMat[{{3, 1}, {2, 2}}]
(* {{3/Sqrt[10], 1/Sqrt[10]}, {-(1/Sqrt[10]), 3/Sqrt[10]}}*)
```

But in Mathematica I would program it like this:

```
o[y_] := Module[{m = Last@Dimensions@y, x = y, n = Normalize},
  x[[1]] = n@x[[1]];
  (x[[#2]] = n[x[[#2]] - Dot @@ x[[{##}]] n@x[[#1]]]) & @@@ Subsets[Range@m, {2}];
  x]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am well aware of the on-board functions giving the valid results. Yet this is to minimize time usage on exam relevant subjects, thus I am making pre-made modules giving me the results i seek, showing the basis of my knowledge.

Thanks for the help though, it gives me some insight in how to solve some related trouble.

On another subject, is there a directory to look up, on the programming language of mathematica, in more detail? 

The language is a bit unfamiliar to me in regard to usage of #, @ and other reference paramters.

Comment: @Bijaelo http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/193

Answer (score 1):

Define functions with `SetDelayed` (i.e., `:=`), not with `Set` (i.e., `=`).  Also, Mma passes by value, so you will need to start out with something like

```
OrtMat[mX_] := Module[{X = mX, m = Dimensions[mX][[2]]}, ...
```

Be sure to return the value you produce.

Comment: The problem isn't the "pass by value" but the immutability. Other languages "pass by value" but you can change the value of the local variable

Comment: Well that cannot quite be the right description either, as the list *is* mutable.  I though Mma types summarized this behavior by calling it pass by value, even thought that will not suit the comp sci types (as there is no copying).  I think the right description is something like this: it may look (in a function definition) like you have introduced formal parameters to manipulate as lvalues, but bc Mma will simply *replace* those occurences with the arguments, you really only have rvalues.  But I'm not a comp sci type.

Comment: Just in case, I was trying to explain why this fails `f[s_List] := (s = {1}); f[{1}]`

Comment: Sure.  I think it is even more informative to note that this does not work:
`g[s_Integer] := (s += 1; s); g[1]`